# ASP.NET Identity relationship

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-identity

I have a question.
I'm using  ASP.NET CORE Identity(Individual User Accounts). It's already creating a separate database independent of my project. In my project, there are things I need to list that belong to the user. How can I do this ?

`Database1-> ASP.NET CORE Identity Database (this database was created automatically)`

`Database2-> My App database`

In Database2 Example Code;

```
public class Report:BaseModel
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; } //(IT MUST BE ASP.NET USER TABLE)
    public User User { get; set; }  //(IT MUST BE ASP.NET USER TABLE)
}
```

Comment: you cannot establish relationships between databases/schemas. you are left with option to create a bounded context with basic users data in your report context.

Comment: Its OK to modify the tables that Identity creates...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make sure that you have OnModelCreating on your DbContext class with base call

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

then add your class

```
public class Report : BaseModel
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
}
```

then call migrations `add-migration Report` and *`Update-Database`*